# MS Access query automatically insert line with default values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running a query in MS Access to get top 2 rows. If query gets only one row I need to fill second one with N/A. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Query should always show last row with default values. Your query does not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a UNION query as subquery of a `TOP 2` SELECT query.

```
SELECT TOP 2 foo, bar
FROM (
  SELECT foo, bar FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "n/a" AS foo, "n/a" AS bar FROM DummyTableWithOneRecord
)
```

You may need to add some field to force sorting "n/a" to the bottom.

If `Table1` (resp. your original query) can be empty, put two records into `DummyTableWithOneRecord`.